Assigning multiple subnets on route table using cloudformation
I am trying to put multiple subnets on my "SubnetId:" syntax on CloudFormation since I am grouping them per routing table, also I am importing the values from the other stack. Here's the code:
    RouteTableAssociationOpsA:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
        Properties:
          SubnetId:
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${AWS::Stackname}-OpsSubA'
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${AWS::Stackname}-ProdSubA'
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${AWS::Stackname}-DemoSubA'
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${AWS::Stackname}-DevSubA'
          RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

I did different formats such as:

RouteTableAssociationOpsA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        - GroupSets:
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-OpsSubA'
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-ProdSubA'
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-DemoSubA'
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-DevSubA'
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

I am getting JSON error for this.

what's the error are you getting?
